# Access VBA for table content as export file Path

Tags: ms-access, vba, filepath

i am using the code below to output a form in PDF to folder :\Completions Tracker\Drawings and it works ok, but i would like to set the filepath to refer to a table, so it can be changed by an admin person, when at different project, instead of having to change the VBA code each time.

I would like to change the fixed file path string to refer to table data instead `[SettingDrawingFilePathTbl]![Drawing_FilePath].text`
but i get a debug when i change the code, any help would be great

```
Private Sub Command170_Click()
'------Print RFIRegisterInputF form, save input data and close form---------

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "RFIRegisterInputF", acFormatPDF, "E:\Completions Tracker\Drawings" & [Forms]![RFIRegisterInputF]![Query_ID] & Format(Date, "ddmmyy") & ".pdf", True

DoCmd.Close acForm, "RFIRegisterInputF", acSaveYes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a table to hold the document name (ObjectName) and the corresponding path:

```
Private Sub Command170_Click()

    '------Print RFIRegisterInputF form, save input data and close form---------
    Const ObjectName As String = "RFIRegisterInputF"

    Dim OutputFile As String

    OutputFile = DLookup("[Path]", "[TableName]", "ObjectName = '" & ObjectName & "'") & _
        [Forms]![RFIRegisterInputF]![Query_ID] & Format(Date, "ddmmyy") & ".pdf"

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, ObjectName, acFormatPDF, OutputFile, True
    DoCmd.Close acForm, ObjectName, acSaveYes
```

Comment: Excellent, never thought to use a DLookup, thanks Gustav